# How to schedule a job as non-root user in CoreOS

Tags: ssh, scheduling, systemd-timer, coreos

I have a script on my CoreOS machine which look like below, that I am using to ssh to multiple nodes from a list and get required details

```
host_det=$(ssh -Ao StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 -l $user $node "
hostname
docker ps | grep haproxy
sudo df -h |grep abcd ")
```

I am executing ssh using a non-root user which I configured as passworless, and it is working fine if I am executing it as the same user normally. (./ssh.sh)

After I scheduled this script using a systemd timer ssh is asking me password and the script is failing. I know when we use timer it is executing as root user and that's why it is asking password even though I specified my ssh user explicitly. Is there any ways in CoreOS to schedule the timer for non-root users ?

My timer & service files are given below.

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/ssh.timer

[Unit]
Description=Run ssh.service every morning 8:30

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 08:30:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target




cat /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service

[Unit]
Description=Run the ssh script

[Service]

Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/home/user_name/ssh.sh 2>/tmp/date'
```

Comment: Is sudo not an option?

Comment: @RamanSailopal : I don't think it is a user privilege issue. For every nodes it is giving error messages like below

Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Note: I set passwordless entry for my user and it is working fine if I am running normally without using a systemd timer

Comment: I mean using sudo to run the command as another user. (sudo -u <user>)

Comment: Sorry. I really didn't understand your point. Which command I need to try with sudo ?

Comment: (1) Please don’t add details to your question in comments — especially not multi-line error logs. You should [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. (And then, optionally, post a brief comment to tell people to look at your edit.)  (2) I don’t know whether it would have helped, but an “obvious” thing to try would be `sudo -u <your_username> ./ssh.sh`.

Comment: Thanks @G-Man. I am pretty new to stackexchange, sorry for the inconvenience caused. From next time I will be careful about it .

Comment: And Issue resolved after exporting a working `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` using the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define

```
User=user_name
```

in your .service file to have it run as a different user.

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue

I added username to .service file

`[Unit]
Description=Run the ssh script

[Service]

User=user
Group=user
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/home/user_name/ssh.sh 2>/tmp/date' `

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` as the scheduler environment is different from the normal. After exporting a working `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, script started to work as expected. Thanks for your help.